# How to create an FFMpeg filter that takes multiple inputs?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a custom FFMpeg filter that takes two inputs and combines them. I've read /doc/writing_filters.txt, but it only describes the creation of a single-input filter, and I'm not sure how to extrapolate from it for the creation of filter with multiple inputs. I've tried reading vf_blend.c and f_interleave.c, but both seem to have a significantly different structure than the vf_edgedetect.c example.

Is there a good guide that explains filter creation in general, or that takes an existing filter with multiple inputs and deconstructs it in order to explain what it does?

Comment: If you intent to submit it to FFmpeg for inclusion feel free to ask for help in the #ffmpeg-devel IRC channel on Freenode.